# Rails : NameError in PicsController#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I tried add an Update function and I am encountering following error.

**undefined local variable or method `pic' for # Did you mean? @pic**

> Extracted source (around line #30):
>
> ```
>      28 end 
>      29 def update
>      30  if @pic.update(pic.params)
>      31   redirect_to @pic, notice: "Updated!!"
>      32  else
>      33    render 'edit'
> ```

My **pics_controller.rb** file is as follows

```
class PicsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_pic, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @pics = Pic.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end
  def show
  end
  def new
    @pic = Pic.new
  end
  def create
    @pic = Pic.new(pic_params)
    if @pic.save
      redirect_to @pic,notice: "Yesss! It was posted!"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  def edit
  end 
  def update
    if @pic.update(pic.params) 
      redirect_to @pic, notice: "Updated!!"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
  private
   def pic_params
    params.require(:pic).permit(:title, :description)
  end
  def find_pic
    @pic = Pic.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there's no `pic` variable in the scope of the update method, then isn't possible to access to it.

I think what you need is the method `pic_params` instead trying to access a local variable called pic and to params, try updating your code to:

```
if @pic.update(pic_params) 
  redirect_to @pic, notice: 'Updated!!'
else
  render 'edit'
end
```